# Finding record which doesn't contain some value in array fields

Tags: sql, node.js, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize + typescript over node (with postgresql db) and I have the following model:

```
id: number,
someField: string,
arr1: number[],
arr2: number[]
```

and I'm trying to find all records in which `arr1` and `arr2` don't contain a certain value.
As far as I've seen my only option in one query is a mix between `Op.not` and `Op.contains`,
so I've tried the following queries:

```
/// Number 1
where: {
            arr1: {
                [Op.not] : {[Op.contains]: [someValue]}
            },
            arr2: {
                 [Op.not] : {[Op.contains]: [soemValue]}
            }
        },
/// Number 2
where: {
            [Op.not]: [
                 {arr1: {[Op.contains]: [someValue]}},
                 {arr2: {[Op.contains]: [someValue]}}
             ]
         },
```

Now, number 1 does compile in typescript but when trying to run it the following error returns:

```
{
    "errorId": "db.failure",
    "message": "Database error occurred",
    "innerError":
    {
        "name": "SequelizeValidationError",
        "errors":
        [
            {
                "message": "{} is not a valid array",
                "type": "Validation error",
                "path": "arr1",
                "value": {},
                "origin": "FUNCTION",
                "instance": null,
                "validatorKey": "ARRAY validator",
                "validatorName": null,
                "validatorArgs": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So I tried number 2, which didn't compile at all with the following TS error:

```
Type '{ [Op.not]: ({ arr1: { [Op.contains]: [number]; }; } | { arr2: { [Op.contains]: [number]; }; })[]; }' is not assignable to type 'WhereOptions<any>'.
  Types of property '[Op.not]' are incompatible.
    Type '({ arr1: { [Op.contains]: [number]; }; } | { arr2: { [Op.contains]: [number]; }; })[]' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
```

So the question is what am I doing wrong, or in other words, how can I make that query without querying all records and filter using code

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the second option is the correct one, but what was incorrect was the types of sequelize, @ts-ignore fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `notIn` and not contain maybe then it will work:

> Official Docs: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html

```
where: {
        arr1: {
               [Op.notIn]: someValueArray
        },
        arr2: {
               [Op.notIn]: someValueArray
        }
     },
```

Comment: That's not the correct action I'm seeking, my data type is array, notIn is for querying if a singular data type is in an array of given values, I'm looking for the opposite, making sure a given value is not inside the array which is part of my model

Comment: Did you try constructing a raw query first?